# How to i replace regex patterns using preg_replace function?

Tags: php, regex

I have url like below

```
/test/(?<name>\w+)/(?<id>\d+)/
```

I want to replace it using preg_replace() function like this

```
/test/name/(?<id>\d+)/
```

I tried this but it does not work as i expected.

```
$subject = '/test/(?<name>\w+)/(?<id>\d+)/';

preg_replace('#\(.*\<name\>.*\)#', 'name', $subject);
```

Comment: Its a regex to see if it is a url. @anubhava

Comment: This question seems unclear to me.  Do your input strings contain named capture groups? and you are trying to match regex patterns?  What is the coding intent/logic here?  What is the desired final result?  I don't get it.

Comment: @mixmackusa Actually this is a route "/test/(?<name>\w+)/(?<id>\d+)/" that i used in a RouteCollectton class  which i want to replace  regex groups to generate url like this. /test/{name}/{id}  So this regex function preg_replace('#\(.*\<name\>[^)]+\)#', 'name', $subject); convert route arguments to real url with provided parameters  e.g. /test/name/54 the solution is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take all the characters until the next "`)`" using `[^)]+`.

```
$subject = '/test/(?<name>\w+)/(?<id>\d+)/';
$subject = preg_replace('#\(.*\<name\>[^)]+\)#', 'name', $subject);
echo $subject;
```

Outputs :

```
/test/name/(?<id>\d+)/
```

Comment: Yes it works fine ! This is the pattern for id  \([^)]+\<id\>[^)]+\).
i added to same pattern to beginning of the regex to prevent replacement of  (?<name>\w+). Many  Thanks :)